# meaning of tensor "component"

Tags: notation, tensors

In Schutz, Geometrical Methods of Mathematical Physics, it is written

> The components of a tensor are its values when it takes basis vectors and one-forms as arguments.

It then gives an abstract example of S, a (3,2) tensor, which has components

> $S^{ijk}_{lm} = S(\omega^i,\omega^j,\omega^k, e_l,e_m)$

Then (same page) it says:

> Prove that a general (2,0) tensor cannot be expressed
>   as a simple outer product of two vectors. Hint: count the number of components
>   a (2,0) tensor may have.

My question:  reading what it says, I think the answer should be that there are an infinite number
of components.  By this, I am interpreting the definition as saying that you contract the
tensor with the various vectors and one forms, resulting in a scalar, and there are an infinite 
number of such values that it could take on.

Obviously this is not what is meant.  So, what is a "component"? 
Let's take the case of a (1,1) tensor in 3 dimensions, call it $M$.
$M$ can be represented as 9 numbers.  Also let's take a one form $w$, which can be represented
as 3 numbers, and a vector v, also three numbers.

Is a component:

- the single number that is $w\, M \, v$ for some particular choice of $w,v,M$?
- the infinity of values of $w\, M\, v$ for all choices of $w,v$?
- the 9 numbers that make up $M$?
- the 6 numbers thst make up $w,v$?
- the 9+6 numbers that make up $w \, M \, v$
- ...?

Comment: Not every vector and not every one-form is in whatever basis you've picked.  For your (1,1) tensor in 3 dimensions, there are three basis vectors and 3 basis 1-forms.  Each of the nine choices of "one of each" will contract with your tensor to give a single component.  Thus, there are only nine components.

Comment: So the vector v must be a basis vector, not an arbitrary vector? (and likewise w must be a "basis form")?  If so, I see there are 9 possible values for the contraction.

Comment: Yes...  "when it takes **basis** vectors and one-forms as arguments".